# animated.view resets to 0 while using PanGestureHandler from react-native-gesture-handler

Tags: react-native

I'm building a slideable chat screen similar to the Discord mobile application. In my current implementation, I have an Animated.View that represents the chat screen. When I swipe it to approximately 20% of the screen, it's supposed to automatically slide to 80% of the screen. However, I'm facing an issue where even a slight swipe causes the animation to reset to 0, as shown in this GIF .I'm seeking guidance from the community on how to fix this issue. The problem is that even a small swipe resets the animation to 0, which should not happen. Any suggestions or corrections are appreciated.

[image]

```
  const translateX = new Animated.Value(0);
  const [direction, setDirection] = useState(null);
  const onPanGestureEvent = Animated.event(
    [
      {
        nativeEvent: {
          translationX: translateX,
        },
      },
    ],
    {useNativeDriver: false},
  );

  const onPanHandlerStateChange = event => {
    console.log(event.nativeEvent.translationX);
    if (event.nativeEvent.oldState === State.ACTIVE) {
      const finalTranslateX = event.nativeEvent.translationX;
      const screenWidth = wp('100%');
      const translateThreshold = screenWidth * 0.2;

      if (finalTranslateX >= translateThreshold) {
        // Swipe right
        Animated.timing(translateX, {
          toValue: screenWidth * 0.8,
          duration: 250,
          useNativeDriver: false,
        }).start();
      } else if (finalTranslateX <= -translateThreshold) {
        // Swipe left
        Animated.timing(translateX, {
          toValue: -screenWidth * 0.8,
          duration: 250,
          useNativeDriver: false,
        }).start();
      } else if (
        finalTranslateX <= translateThreshold ||
        finalTranslateX >= translateThreshold
      ) {
        Animated.timing(translateX, {
          toValue: -screenWidth * 0,
          duration: 250,
          useNativeDriver: false,
        }).start();
      } else {
        // No significant swipe, reset to the original position
        // Animated.spring(translateX, {
        //   toValue: 0,
        //   useNativeDriver: false,
        // }).start();
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.parent}>
      <PanGestureHandler
        onGestureEvent={onPanGestureEvent}
        onHandlerStateChange={onPanHandlerStateChange}>
        <Animated.View
          style={[
            styles.testBox,
            {
              transform: [
                {
                  translateX: translateX,
                },
              ],
            },
          ]}
        />
      </PanGestureHandler>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```